# Como concatenar um objeto com uma variável para ser dinâmico?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Galera tenho problema em angular

Tenho meu objeto

```
user = {name: 'Alexandre', email: 'alexandre@200horas.com.br'}
```

Eu preciso de um jeito para mostrar no console

```
    var attr  = 'name';
    var attr2 = 'email';
    insira o código aqui
    console.log(user.attr) e me retorne Alexandre;
    console.log(user.attr2) e me retorne 'Alexandre@200horas.com.br;
```

O segundo parâmetro do objeto seria dinamicamente variável, como posso executar?

já tentei assim e nada certo

```
user.attr;
user.{attr};
user.(attr);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se eu entendi bem, você pode acessar as propriedades do objeto usando a seguinte notação:

```
var attr  = 'name';
var attr2 = 'email';

console.log(user[attr]) // mesmo que "user.name"
// => 'Alexandre'

console.log(user[attr2]) // mesmo que "user.email"
// => 'Alexandre@200horas.com.br'
```

Mais informações [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: Obrigado eu não sabia que dava para acessar como tipo array no indice

Answer (score 1):

```
var user = '{"name": "Alexandre", "email": "alexandre@200horas.com.br"}';
var usuario = JSON.parse(user);

for (var x in usuario) {
   console.log(usuario[x]);
}
```

Comment: problema nem é este, problema e mostrar com variável.

Comment: Acho que não entendi muito bem. Pode ser mais claro?

Comment: eu tenho um objeto user nele contem name,email eu vou receber esses 2 parametrso dinamicamente ou seja

ira ficar user.$variavel e user.$variavel2

Comment: Agora acho que entendi.Veja minha resposta editada.

Comment: E aí? Funcionou?

Answer (score 0):

```
 user = {name: 'Alexandre', email: 'alexandre@200horas.com.br'}

 var attr  = 'user.name';
 var attr2 = 'user.email';

 console.log(attr , attr2) retorna => "Alexandre" "Alexandre@200horas.com.br"
```